# ¿Como enviar dos parámetros a un ActionResult en ASP MVc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

tengo el siguiente script:

```
    $('#btnCreate').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#btnCreate').attr('data-modal', '');
    $('#btnCreate').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    $('#myModalContent').load(this.href + '/' + $('#companyId').val(), function () {

        $('#myModal').modal({
            /*backdrop: 'static',*/
            keyboard: true
        }, 'show');
        bindForm(this);
        $('#btnCreate').removeAttr('data-modal');
        $('#btnCreate').removeAttr('data-toggle');
    });
    return false;
});
```

El cual debe de enviarme dos parámetros a este ActionResult:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateByCompany(int id,int proveedorId)
{
    var bancoViewModel = new BancoViewModel();
    bancoViewModel.BancosNombresViewModel = GetBancosNombres();
    bancoViewModel.CompañiaId = id;
    bancoViewModel.ProveedorId = proveedorId;

    return View(bancoViewModel);
}
```

Estos parámetros los estará tomando de dos elementos ocultos:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CompañiaId, new { @id = "companyId"})
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ProveedorId, new { @id = "proveedorId" })
```

Tal cual como esta en este momento solo me esta enviando el valor correspondiente a "companyId".

**¿De que manera podría enviarle el valor de estos parámetros a mi ActionResult?**

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente deberías hacer una petición Ajax con método GET (ya que tienes decorada la acción con el atributo HttpGet) enviando los valores como caves id (compañía) y proveedorId (proveedor).

Este sería un ejemplo simple:

```
$('#btnCreate').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax('@Url.Action("CreateByCompany")', {
        data: { id: $('#companyId').val(), proveedorId: $('#proveedorId').val() },
        method: 'GET'
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#myModalContent').html(data);
    });
});
```

También tienes la opción de utilizar las extensiones Ajax con la librería Microsoft.jQuery.Unobstrusive.Ajax:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Crear", "CreateByCompany",
        new
        {
            id = Model.CompaniaId,
            proveedorId = Model.ProveedorId
        },
        new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "Get",
            UpdateTargetId = "myModalContent",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        });
```

Este ejemplo crea un link que envía los valores de CompaniaId y ProveedorId a la acción CreateByCompany y establece el contenido devuelto como contenido del elemento myModalContent.

Comment: Hola Asier: La segunda respuesta es algo interesante, ese fragmento de código iría en el botón que dispara la acción?, ya antes había intentado algo así pero me perdí en donde llamar a ese helper de ajax..

Comment: No, ese código genera directamente un link con el texto "Crear" y que al pulsarlo genera la petición Ajax.

Comment: Recuerda que para poder utilizarlo necesitarás incluir la librería jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: Hola Asier: Probe con la forma que me indicas pero recibo este mensaje de error **Se detectó un posible valor Request.Path peligroso en el cliente (<).]**  este es parte del script que estoy ejecutando: 'success: function (result) {
                $('#myModalContent').load(result, function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal({'

Comment: No debería, y menos teniendo en cuenta que los datos que se pasan son enteros. Este error salta cuando .NET detecta en alguno de los datos enviados algo (como un carácter <) que puede indicar que se está intentando realizar un ataque de Cross Site Scripting.
Habría que ver el código para ver dónde está el problema.

Comment: También puedes utilizar las Developer Tools de tu navegador (se suelen abrir pulsando F12) para ver exactamente qué información se está enviando al servidor. En la pestaña Red (o Network) te aparecen todas las peticiones que se realizan y puedes ver los datos que envías al servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar "ajax" algo asi:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetUnitDateRangeParamsVals", "UnitReportDateRangeParams")',
    data: { unit: unitval, report: 1 },
    cache: false,
    success: function (returneddata) {
        populatedaterangeprams(1, returneddata);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('error in GetUnitDateRangeParamsVals.1');
    }
});
```

Aqui es el metodo al Controller:

```
public class UnitReportDateRangeParamsController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult GetUnitDateRangeParamsVals(string unit, int report)
    {
        UnitReportDateRangeParamsModel model = new UnitReportDateRangeParamsModel();
        try
        {
            string qry = string.Format(SQL.UnitReportDateRangeQuery, unit, report);
            DataTable DateRangeParamsValsDT = SQL.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(
                qry,
                CommandType.Text,
                null
                );

            UnitReportDateRangeParamsModel.DateRangeParams daterangeparams =
                (from DataRow row in DateRangeParamsValsDT.Rows
                 select new UnitReportDateRangeParamsModel.DateRangeParams
                 {
                     TimeUnitsFrom = Convert.ToInt32(row["ParamBeginRange"]),
                     TimeUnitsTo = Convert.ToInt32(row["ParamEndRange"])
                 }).Single();

            model.daterangeparams = daterangeparams;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Arriba tiene el Controller un string y un int, pero debe ser bastante semajante para ti.

Comment: Hola Clay: Gracias por tu respuesta, el tema es que el result de ese Action es una vista la cual muestro como Modal, entonces la linea que me provoca conflicto es esta:  **$('#myModalContent').load(this.href + '/' + $('#companyId').val()** ya que aquí es donde tengo que pasar los parámetros, entiendo el uso de ajax hasta cierto nivel pero no logro ver como adaptar lo que me ofreces a la linea mencionada. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Que tipo de formulario tienes?

No recuerdo en que versión en adelante de MVC es posible enviar el modelo y el binding lo hace el framework automaticamente. solo debes esperar el modelo de la vista en el controlador.

ejemplo:

controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Formulario(ModelTest model)
        {


            throw new NotImplementedException("s");
        }
    }
```

modelo

```
public class ModelTest
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public string Palabra { get; set; }
    }
```

Vista

```
@model ModelTest

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Formulario", "Home"))
{ 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Numero)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Palabra)

    <input type="submit">
}
```

cuando llenes los campos podras ver que el modelo se traspasa automaticamente al controlador, esto lo hice en vs2015 community.

puedes colocar un punto de interrupcion en la excepcion y podras revisar que el modelo trae todos los valores. el primero es un numero y el segundo un string.

saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estás mandando parámetros por Url, por lo que debes quitar la "/" después del load, cambiarla por un ? y luego poner los parámetros que necesites y su valor, separados por &:

```
.load(this.href + '?id=' + $('#companyId').val()+"&proveedorId="$('#id').val();
```